# Layered navigation filter toolbar not opened on click in mobile

Tags: magento2

Layered navigation  filter toolbar not opened on click in mobile[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the link to open the filters in mobile view. It works in Luma and in Magento Blank well. But not in my Theme, javascript to click open seems to not work

Comment: roykon.dk check this link

Comment: on listing page

Comment: okay i will check update your as soon as

Comment: thanks i am waitng

Comment: Hello in my mobile phone and desktop filter is working fine

Comment: can you please check clean cache your browser and after check...